# Should Version be part of the DTO returned by the api?

Tags: java, rest, etag

I have entities with a version field.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "meals", catalog = "nutrientTracker")
public class Meal implements Entity<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @Column(name = "foods")
    private String foods;

    @Column(name = "eaten")
    private boolean eaten;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private float price;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private double longitude;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private long version;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

In the context of my application, I consider the version field as an ETag.
My DTO is as follows:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MealDTO implements DTO<Meal, Long> {
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "-1", value = "id")
    private long id;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "tasty", value = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "1994-11-05T13:15:30Z", value = "date")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "1605294438", value = "dateEpoch")
    private long dateEpoch;

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "banana,apple", value = "foods")
    private String foods;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "false", value = "eaten")
    private boolean eaten;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "6.9", value = "price")
    private float price;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "69.6969696969", value = "latitude")
    private double latitude;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "42.0420420420", value = "longitude")
    private double longitude;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "1", value = "userId")
    private long userId;

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "1", value = "etag")
    private String etag;
}
```

where I map the version to the ETag field.

My question is as follows:

Should I return the ETag from the API as a field? Or to have it just in the Headers? Is it bad practice to have it in the entity itself?
On the client-side I do something like:

```
const result: Meal = response.data;
result.etag = response.headers['etag'];
return result;
```

anyways. Is this bad practice also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The version column is used for when doing certain operations against the database and as such should not be exposed to the user of the API. Per the [@Version](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Version.html) docs:

> Specifies the version field or property of an entity class that serves as its optimistic lock value. The version is used to ensure integrity when performing the merge operation and for optimistic concurrency control.

Comment: Ok, I instead used it in an MD5 Hash for my ETag alongside some server-side key. Is that good?

Comment: Yes. I would think so.